# Not seeing file upload destination radios for image field in custom blocks. Where is the fault?

Tags: 8, blocks, files

Scratching my head with this. I am working with a custom block and have added an image field. However the Upload destination radios are not present and this results in a file storage error. ' Illegal choice public in Upload destination element'

Two screenshots attached. The first indicates what I am seeing, the second (from a different site) is how it should look.

I am only seeing this problem with custom blocks and find that regular content types are okay. Not just with image storage; files too.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like your schemas aren't _Visible, readable and writeable._, per [`StreamWrapperInterface:: WRITE_VISIBLE `](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StreamWrapper%21StreamWrapperInterface.php/constant/StreamWrapperInterface%3A%3AWRITE_VISIBLE/8.1.x). Only schemas that satisfy those conditions are added to the array of radios

Comment: Thank you @Clive I think I have tracked this down to a custom module